# A double replace in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

So I'm a bit stuck on a problem. I am taking a file and writing a new file with the correct atom number replacements.

**BackGround**

[image]

So currently my code looks for the pattern of O, H, H2, O in the data at line[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYU5t.png)
It looks for pattern and replaces the oxygen atoms with numbering 7 and 8. and whatever 7 and 8 lines were are now assigned the numbers the first O and the second O was on.

```
if line[4] == "O" and H[4] == "H" and H2[4:6] == "H2" and O[4] == "O":

                #Remember the line numbers to change the latter half what they are attached to

                lineNumberOfFirstOxygen = line[1:3]
                lineNumberOfSecondOxygen = O[1:3]
                secondOxygenExists = True

                #Relace the lines
                newf.write(line.replace(line[1:3], " 7"))
                newf.write(O.replace(O[1:3], " 8"))
                newf.write(line1.replace(" 7", line[1:3]))
                newf.write(line2.replace(" 8", O[1:3]))
```

like so. The important factor is that recogninzes what line numbers the first O and the Second O was on so in this example 56 and 59 are the numbers.

**The Problem**

There are bonds associated with each atom number like so.

[image]

So the way I wrote the code so far is that it does the switch of the 7 and 8 with the corresponding first and second O atom numbers.

```
 if line[1:3] == " 7":
    bondLine1 = line
 elif line[1:3] == " 8":
    bondLine2 = line



 bondSecondO = lines[i + 3]

 if line[1:3] == lineNumberOfFirstOxygen and bondSecondO[1:3] == lineNumberOfSecondOxygen:

    newf.write(line.replace(line[1:3], ' 7'))
    newf.write(bondSecondO.replace(bondSecondO[1:3], ' 8'))
    newf.write(bondLine1.replace(' 7', line[1:3]))
    newf.write(bondLine2.replace(' 8', bondSecondO[1:3]))
```

The second part to changing the bond numbers is that the each other atom that was connected to that previous number now has to switch accordingly to the new reassigned number.

[image]

So above the image of atoms 6, 9, 10, 11 there 7 needs to be replaced with the number 37 and for number 9 the 8 needs to be replace with a 40. The code I wrote was simple enough and does just that but then I encounter two problems.

**The Code in Question**

```
 if line[1:3] == " 7" or line[1:3] == " 8" or line[1:3] == lineNumberOfFirstOxygen or line[1:3] == lineNumberOfSecondOxygen:
                continue
            else:

                for j in line.split():
                    if j == lineNumberOfFirstOxygen:
                        newf.write(line.replace(j, " 7"))
                        wroteLine = True
                    elif j == lineNumberOfSecondOxygen:
                        newf.write(line.replace(j, " 8"))
                        wroteLine = True
                    elif j == "7":
                        newf.write(line.replace(" 7", lineNumberOfFirstOxygen))
                        wroteLine = True
                    elif j == "8":
                        newf.write(line.replace(" 8", lineNumberOfSecondOxygen))
                        wroteLine = True

                if wroteLine:
                    wroteLine = False
                    continue
                else:
                    newf.write(line)
```

This is the ending result

[image]

I can see the flaw there where it will write both lines of the data because it sees both and hence behold to lines with the nine attached.How do I get the code to recognize when there is two values that need to be changed and write them to the same line in the nested for loop?